# PeerJS call other peer on a div click

Tags: javascript, peerjs

im starting with PeerJS and Javascript in General.

I wanted to fire an Information to another peer on click on a div:

```
<script src="http://cdn.peerjs.com/0.3/peer.js"></script>
<script>
  var peer = new Peer('sane-03', {key: '97za6osy6ulkgldi'}); 
  var conn = peer.connect('sanen-02');
  document.getElementById("1").onclick = function() {
  conn.on('open', function(){ conn.send('hi!');});
  };
</script>
```

I believe the function in the function is causing the conn.send not to work.
I will try to find an answer on the web, but some starting help would be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is in the wrong place. You need to set the  .on handler before sending the text

```
  var peer = new Peer('sane-03', {key: '97za6osy6ulkgldi'}); 
  var conn = peer.connect('sanen-02');
  if (conn) {
      conn.on('open', function(){ 
          conn.send('hi, connection opened!');
      });
  }
  document.getElementById("1").onclick = function() {
      conn.send('Hello again');
  };
```

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out. It worked perfectly!